# What does the +20% bonus from Heavy Infantry Leader, etc. apply to?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Leadership traits (Heavy Infantry Leader, Light Foot Leader, Cavalry Leader, Elephant Leader) give "+20%" to their respective unit types...

But +20% to what? Morale? Defense? Damage? # of troops you are considered to have for purposes of tactic selection?